# java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException while running INSERT query in ojdbc8

Tags: java, ojdbc

While trying to run an INSERT query as follows:

```
javax.persistence.Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(MY_NATIVE_QUERY);
return query.executeUpdate();
```

from my Java application I am getting the below error:

```
java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: null
at oracle.net.ano.CryptoNIONSDataChannel.readDataFromSocketChannel(Unknown Source) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.prepareForReading(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:98) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:534) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:485) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:252) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:612) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:226) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:59) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:910) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1119) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3780) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeInternal(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1343) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3865) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3845) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1061) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:211) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.executeNativeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1346) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.executeUpdate(SQLQueryImpl.java:389) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.internalExecuteUpdate(QueryImpl.java:371) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:78) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
```

Database in use is Oracle 10g and jdbc driver in use is ojdbc8-12.2.0.1. The insert query is a simple insert which selects data from a join of 2 tables and inserts in another one.

Moreover, I don't get this exception in development and it only occurs in production. I came across a solution [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/733697) which says its an internal Oracle driver bug and advises to upgrade to latest 10g driver. But I already have 12c driver. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: If you "select from two tables and insert the result", my guess would be that your selects do return an empty result. Log your statements in production and isolate the selects. Run those in a SQL-Tool of your choice and validate the result.

Comment: @Nikolas... thanks for the reply. I have already tested scenarios with empty results in development environment and it runs fine.

Comment: MY_NATIVE_QUERY being what exactly?

Comment: @ankit3j, please elaborate your `MY_NATIVE_QUERY` in question.

Comment: Its a simple SQL INSERT query and not a JPQL.

Comment: Thanks all for answers

Answer (score 1):

It looks like 12.2.0.1 has a bug leading sometimes to this problem. It also seems to depend on the environment and the query. I came across one query that was fetching a BLOB where the problem occurs reliably in many environments and many other queries do fail in rare setups, but if they do fail, this can be reliably reproduced in those specific setups (network, DB). As of today 12.2.0.1 still seems to be the latest version available.

It looks like with 12.1.0.2 this problem cannot be reproduced. However 12.1.0.2 seems to have issues with Oracle Wallet. So if you come across the problem with NegativeArraySizeException and if you do not use Oracle Wallet, then going for 12.1.0.2 instead of 12.2.0.1 should work for you.

Tested with Oracle 12c DB.

Answer (score 1):

`oracle.net.ano.CryptoNIONSDataChannel` tells that you have some kind of encryption enabled (Oracle Native Encryption probably).

You can check if you use SSL/TLS encryption with the following query:

```
select sys_context('userenv', 'network_protocol') from dual;

-- SSL/TLS connecion will return "tcps" here
```

You can check if you have oralce native encryption or checksumming with the following query:

```
select network_service_banner from v$session_connect_info
 where sid = sys_context('userenv','sid')
   and network_service_banner like '%crypt%service adapter%';

-- you'll get something like "AES256 encryption service adapter"
-- and/or "SHA1 crypto-checksumming service adapter"
```

So if you are using encryption, try to disable it first and try again. If you need to use it try to switch from thin to oci8 driver, or try diffent version (12.1.0.2 or 11.2.0.4)

Answer (score 0):

My solution (just stumbled upon this irritating thing):

1. Do the pre-check executing "select 1 from dual" before the right query
2. If it fails (got this exception), reset the connectionPool as follows:

```
if(connection == null || connection.isClosed())
{
     connection = connectionFactory.getConnection();
}
            
if(!checkConnection(connection))
{
     connectionFactory.reset();
     connection = connectionFactory.getConnection();
}
```

The class

```
public class ConnectionFactory implements org.apache.commons.dbcp2.ConnectionFactory
{
...
    PoolingDataSource<PoolableConnection> dataSource = null;
...
    public void reset()
    {
        try
        {
            dataSource.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        dataSource = null;
    }

    public Connection getConnection() throws Exception
    {
        if (dataSource == null)
        {
            this.createConnectionPool();
        }
        
        try
        {
            return dataSource.getConnection();
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private synchronized void createConnectionPool() throws Exception
    {

        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = this;
        PoolableConnectionFactory poolableConnectionFactory = new PoolableConnectionFactory(connectionFactory, null);
         
        connectionPool = new GenericObjectPool<>(poolableConnectionFactory);
        connectionPool.setMaxTotal(5);
        connectionPool.setMinIdle(1);
        
        poolableConnectionFactory.setPool(connectionPool);
        dataSource = new PoolingDataSource<>(connectionPool);
    }
}
```

Not the perfect one, but works for me.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Using the following version (19.7.0.0) fixed this issue based on my testing.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
   <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
   <version>19.7.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The trouble version was 12.2.0.1

Related oracle support page https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/2490793_1.html